# jQuery validate stays valid after ajax postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form that with a validator that works the first time but not the second time. The code validates on the client side without any problem but as soon as the form is submitted and the form is partially render although fields are invalid the $('form').valid() continues returning true always.

The data is validated at the server side but then the error is displayed twice. My rules are set by MVC4 generated code thus rules are correctly initiated.

Not sure if is possible re-validate the form. Please note that $('form').validate() does not work. It returns the validator and valid() returns true all the time.

Here the options. displayErrors function find the html element that shows the errors.

```
/* Set additional settings for the validator */
        var options = {
            onfocusout: false,
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                displayErrors(errorList, false);
            }
        };
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: First, show enough code... second, please don't use irrelevant tags.  [tag:jquery-validation-engine] is a totally different plugin.

Comment: `$('form').validate()` is the initialization method and can only be called once.  Subsequent calls are ignored.  Your framework is probably automatically calling `.validate()` on page load.  Yes, you can validate the form more than once... that's what the `.valid()` method can do... however, too much code is missing from your OP to say where you're going wrong.

Comment: I know your code is automatically generated by your framework, so open the browser, look at source, and pull out the relevant bits... the jQuery, the HTML markup for the form, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky for the clarification. I which I could paste the whole code for you but one the partial render is made chrome does not show other than a blank file and line numbers. I understand the jquery.validate can only be initialize once thus in a $().ready we extend the validator settings.

Then it comes the Begin form: 

<div id="formHolder">
using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })){
<div>
 Html.TextBoxFor(...)
</div>
}
</div>

So the $.ajax({....,
success: function(r){ $('#formHolder').html(r); } });

Replaces the new html in the #formholder element.

Comment: That's impossible.  Every browser will show the rendered HTML code for the entire page.

Comment: It does not show after a postback to me. I figured this out.

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing about the ajax post that would cause anything in the loaded page DOM to change... i.e.  the validation should continue to function just fine.  As in this jsFiddle, you can validate, submit and re-validate an unlimited number of times.  http://jsfiddle.net/jun25/

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing something like this

```
$vlt = $('#myForm').validate(); //-- get validator
$vlt.checkForm(); 

if ( $('#myForm').valid()){
//-- code
}
```

It seems like doing it in this way the validator was able to picked the new changes. Not sure if I mention that the form was being re-render and replaced by $('#okok').html(newStuff);

Anyway, I could maybe conclude, I won't recommend this plugin to a friend :))